# How to get geojson layer properties in the div using OpenLayers3 method?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have tried to display a geojson with OpenLayers3, here geojson file having sample data like

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"AFG","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.210817,35.650072],[62.230651,35.270664],[62.984662,35.404041],[63.193538,35.857166],[63.982896,36.007957],[64.546479,36.312073],[64.746105,37.111818],[65.588948,37.305217],[65.745631,37.661164],[66.217385,37.39379],[66.518607,37.362784],[67.075782,37.356144],[67.83,37.144994],[68.135562,37.023115],[68.859446,37.344336],[69.196273,37.151144],[69.518785,37.608997],[70.116578,37.588223],[70.270574,37.735165],[70.376304,38.138396],[70.806821,38.486282],[71.348131,38.258905],[71.239404,37.953265],[71.541918,37.905774],[71.448693,37.065645],[71.844638,36.738171],[72.193041,36.948288],[72.63689,37.047558],[73.260056,37.495257],[73.948696,37.421566],[74.980002,37.41999],[75.158028,37.133031],[74.575893,37.020841],[74.067552,36.836176],[72.920025,36.720007],[71.846292,36.509942],[71.262348,36.074388],[71.498768,35.650563],[71.613076,35.153203],[71.115019,34.733126],[71.156773,34.348911],[70.881803,33.988856],[69.930543,34.02012],[70.323594,33.358533],[69.687147,33.105499],[69.262522,32.501944],[69.317764,31.901412],[68.926677,31.620189],[68.556932,31.71331],[67.792689,31.58293],[67.683394,31.303154],[66.938891,31.304911],[66.381458,30.738899],[66.346473,29.887943],[65.046862,29.472181],[64.350419,29.560031],[64.148002,29.340819],[63.550261,29.468331],[62.549857,29.318572],[60.874248,29.829239],[61.781222,30.73585],[61.699314,31.379506],[60.941945,31.548075],[60.863655,32.18292],[60.536078,32.981269],[60.9637,33.528832],[60.52843,33.676446],[60.803193,34.404102],[61.210817,35.650072]]]}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"AGO","properties":{"name":"Angola"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[16.326528,-5.87747],[16.57318,-6.622645],[16.860191,-7.222298],[17.089996,-7.545689],[17.47297,-8.068551],[18.134222,-7.987678],[18.464176,-7.847014],[19.016752,-7.988246],[19.166613,-7.738184],[19.417502,-7.155429],[20.037723,-7.116361],[20.091622,-6.94309],[20.601823,-6.939318],[20.514748,-7.299606],[21.728111,-7.290872],[21.746456,-7.920085],[21.949131,-8.305901],[21.801801,-8.908707],[21.875182,-9.523708],[22.208753,-9.894796],[22.155268,-11.084801],[22.402798,-10.993075],[22.837345,-11.017622],[23.456791,-10.867863],[23.912215,-10.926826],[24.017894,-11.237298],[23.904154,-11.722282],[24.079905,-12.191297],[23.930922,-12.565848],[24.016137,-12.911046],[21.933886,-12.898437],[21.887843,-16.08031],[22.562478,-16.898451],[23.215048,-17.523116],[21.377176,-17.930636],[18.956187,-17.789095],[18.263309,-17.309951],[14.209707,-17.353101],[14.058501,-17.423381],[13.462362,-16.971212],[12.814081,-16.941343],[12.215461,-17.111668],[11.734199,-17.301889],[11.640096,-16.673142],[11.778537,-15.793816],[12.123581,-14.878316],[12.175619,-14.449144],[12.500095,-13.5477],[12.738479,-13.137906],[13.312914,-12.48363],[13.633721,-12.038645],[13.738728,-11.297863],[13.686379,-10.731076],[13.387328,-10.373578],[13.120988,-9.766897],[12.87537,-9.166934],[12.929061,-8.959091],[13.236433,-8.562629],[12.93304,-7.596539],[12.728298,-6.927122],[12.227347,-6.294448],[12.322432,-6.100092],[12.735171,-5.965682],[13.024869,-5.984389],[13.375597,-5.864241],[16.326528,-5.87747]]],[[[12.436688,-5.684304],[12.182337,-5.789931],[11.914963,-5.037987],[12.318608,-4.60623],[12.62076,-4.438023],[12.995517,-4.781103],[12.631612,-4.991271],[12.468004,-5.248362],[12.436688,-5.684304]]]]}},
{"type":"Feature","id":"ALB","properties":{"name":"Albania"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[20.590247,41.855404],[20.463175,41.515089],[20.605182,41.086226],[21.02004,40.842727],[20.99999,40.580004],[20.674997,40.435],[20.615,40.110007],[20.150016,39.624998],[19.98,39.694993],[19.960002,39.915006],[19.406082,40.250773],[19.319059,40.72723],[19.40355,41.409566],[19.540027,41.719986],[19.371769,41.877548],[19.304486,42.195745],[19.738051,42.688247],[19.801613,42.500093],[20.0707,42.58863],[20.283755,42.32026],[20.52295,42.21787],[20.590247,41.855404]]]}}
```

...etc

Code in OpenLayers3 to display geojson on the map

2.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image vector layer example</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.4.0/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.4.0/ol.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div class="span4 pull-right">
      <div id="info" class="alert alert-success">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<script>
var  style_g = new ol.style.Style({
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(192,255,255,0.6)',
                width: 1
              })
            });
             styles_g = [style_g];

var vectorLayer4 = new ol.layer.Vector({
              maxResolution: 0.8,
              source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'countr.geojson',
               format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                  defaultDataProjection:'EPSG:4326'
                })
              }),
              style: styles_g
            });
var mapcenter = [79.60,23.44];
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
     url: 'http://localhost:8089/geoserver/manjula/wms',
                params: {'LAYERS': 'manjula:India_states_UT_geo_wgs84'}
                //pms:India_states_UT_geo_wgs84
        })
      }),
      vectorLayer4

  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
               center: mapcenter,
               zoom: 5,
               extent: [66.2329, 7.68083, 98.2223, 39.03874],
               maxZoom:16,
               minZoom: 4,
    })
});

var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  map: map,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#f00',
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,25,94,0.6)'
    })
  })
});

var highlight;
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });

  var info = document.getElementById('info');
  //alert(info);
  if (feature) {
    info.innerHTML = feature.getId() + ': ' + feature.get('name');
    alert(info.innerHTML);
  } else {
    info.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  }

  if (feature !== highlight) {
    if (highlight) {
      featureOverlay.removeFeature(highlight);
    }
    if (feature) {
      featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
    }
    highlight = feature;
  }

};

map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
});

map.on('click', function(evt) {
alert();
  displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the geojson is not displaying on the map of OpenLayers3. How can this problem be rectified? After adding geojson to the map I want to display properties of the particular location using latitude and longtitude.

Comment: I tried your code with the geojson on my computer but did not manage to find what's wrong. Note the zoom, maxZoom & minZoom properties of the view don't agree (zoom should be = to maxZoom-minZoom). A tip: use the ol-debug.js library to find out the problem(s).